# How to upload my moduled tex files in arXiv?

Tags: sourcecode, arxiv, directory, modules

My first ever paper was accepted and I want to upload it to arXiv. However it seems a bit difficult, since it doesn't allow you to upload the .pdf right away..I uploaded my main .tex file but when on the Preview tab it will say "Processing your submission may take several minutes." and will never end.

Check the file tree:

```
.
./fig
./fig/cube.pdf
./llncs.cls
./aem.tex    <-- main file that points to 'tex/exp.tex', etc.
./tex
./tex/intro.tex
./tex/discuss.tex
./tex/abbrev.tex
./tex/exp.tex
./tex/impl.tex
./tex/abstract.tex
./tex/aem.bib
./tex/method.tex
```

How should I do it? :/

---

I compile with PDFLatex.

Comment: Which is the main file? The arXiv probably couldn't figure it out.  Take a look at https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#autoignore and add the auto-ignore like to all but the main file.

Comment: So I should upload every single file that my tree has, I guess @LoopSpace, right? Should I insert the `%auto-ignore` in the first line of every tex file (but the main one)?

Comment: Also, I notice that you have the `.bib` file in there.  The arXiv says that you should upload the `.bbl` file instead.  See https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#bibtex

Comment: Yes, upload all of those and add the auto-ignore line to all but the main tex file (the one I'm not sure about is `llncs.cls`; is that a journal-specific class file? If so, do you have permission to upload the *final* version of the paper?)

Comment: Are you sure you submitted that file structure? I don't remember the arxiv allowing one to arrange Tex files into directories etc.

Comment: @innisfree you can do it by uploading a ZIP file with the directory structure.

Comment: @gsamaras is your document meant to be compiled with PDFlatex?

Comment: Dear all, thanks for the comments, but I am now a bit confused. @DavidZ I compile with Xelatex. Can I just upload the .zip file? Loop Space, We had to use `\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper,11pt]{llncs}` to produce the relevant format. However I am not sure on permission issues that you are mentioning.

Comment: @gsamaras Are you sure arXiv supports Xelatex? As far as I know they only allow for compilation with latex or pdflatex.

Comment: I was able to compile with pdflatex too @DavidZ. I do not know what arXiv supports.

Comment: @DavidZ what you said with the .zip actually worked. Can you please post an answer?

Comment: @gsamaras I think I shouldn't, because I'm fairly sure the ZIP file and the directory structure has nothing to do with the problem you're actually asking about. I've had that error before, where my main .tex file was expecting to find something in a subdirectory, but the subdirectory didn't exist. It's nothing like what you've described here. I think you must have stumbled on to something else that solves the problem, while you were experimenting with uploading an archive.

Comment: DavidZ hmm I see your point. Maybe the `%auto-ignore` that @LoopSpace suggested did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

It should work if you:

1. add %auto-ignore to the first line of every text file but the main file
2. compress your file tree

1. prevents arXiv's system from compiling your non-main files independently
2. ensures that your folder structure will be respected and your images inside the *fig* folder will be accessible.

Also, please check that you do not have an \input loop such as this:

file master: \input{a}
file A: \input{b}
file B: \input{a}

Comment: Could you explain why this works. As it is currently written it is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I'll add a full answer.

Comment: @rafaelvalle could you please explain what is meant by your second point: "compress your file tree"? Do we zip the entire folder of the project?

Comment: yes, try zipping the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @gsamaras's answer. To make one single latex file from multiple files, you can use flatex: https://github.com/johnjosephhorton/flatex . Follow the instruction and installl and then `flatex main.tex single_file.tex` will generate the single source file.